# Can screening occur in a gas of harmonic oscillators?

Tags: electric-fields, harmonic-oscillator, plasma-physics, coulombs-law

The screening of the electric field is a known effect that occurs in a gas of charged particles.
Can screening also occur if the electric (Coulomb) interaction is replaced with a harmonic oscillator interaction?

In other words, is there a screening effect in a system of many identical particles, where the interaction force between any pair of particles is proportional to the distance between them?

Comment: Are you asking about Debye screening/shielding?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think I'm talking about an effect where the effective harmonic oscillator's frequency constant decreases at larger distances, due to the presence of many other harmonic oscillators.

Comment: If you assume a plasma (i.e., ionized gas) and make the further assumption of infinitely massive ions (i.e., ignore their movement), then you can get two basic things:  Langmuir waves (also called plasma oscillations) and Debye screening/shielding.  The Debye length is the spatial scale over which the average number of positive and negative charges balance (i.e., the plasma becomes quasi-neutral).  In the 1D case, the E-field strength of any net electric charge is directly proportional to the electron displacement, much like a SHO.